# Providers in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

Thanks for checking out my question, I'm relatively new to AngularJS so any advice would be great.

I'm trying to create a factory/service/provider, but I keep getting errors and can't get it to work right.

here is my Provider:

```
app.provider('createEventProvider', function() {

this.event = {
name: '',
when: '',
where: '',
description: '',
image: ''
};

this.$get = function(){
    var event = this.event;

    return
    {
      getEvent: function() 
      {
        return event
      }
    }
}

  this.setEventData = function(eventProp, data)
  {
    this.event[eventProp] = data;
  };
 });
```

and here is my controller:

```
 app.controller('createEventController', function($scope, createEventProvider){

     $scope.event = createEventProvider.getEvent();
 });
```

When I run my code I get this error message:
*Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )* 
referring to this line of my provider: *this.$get = function(){*

I've been jumping around looking at different tutorials and haven't been able to find the answer. Any help, advice, or tips would be greatly appreciated!

Let me know if you need anymore of my code to solve the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually it's this line part:

```
return
    {
      getEvent: function() 
      {
        return event
      }
    }
```

You're a little overeager with your line returns. Move the object definition start to the return line and you'll be ok:

```
return {
  getEvent: function() {
    return event
  }
}
```

Comment: ahhh, that worked! I didn't know Angular was sensitive to the amount of line returns I used. Thanks :)

Comment: @BradenEricson It's not Angular that's sensitive, it's javascript

Comment: Is it just when you're defining objects that it's sensitive?

Comment: It's actually the return in this case. The browser interpreted it as --return-, -new line-, -define object without variable-. When you're using "return" you have to make to sure include what's being sent on the same line.